# Show ISO-8601 date+time in current time?

Tags: java, timezone, utc

for example, 2012-10-30T22:30:00+0300 need to be shown in 2012-10-30T22:30:00-0600 (the local time for example)
need to implement in java (android app)
how can I manage doing that?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand what you want to achieve. 22:30:00+0300 is not the same time as 22:30:00-0600.

Comment: exactly, I'll give you an example - in case I have an event time in Germany, but currently I'm in London, I need to show the Germany event time in London's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using joda time library solved my problem optimally, using dateTime & dateTime zone like following:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser2 = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
    dt = DateTime.parse("2012-11-05T13:00:00+0200");
    System.out.println(dt.toString());

    dt2 = DateTime.parse("2012-11-05T21:45:00-08:00");
    DateTimeZone dtz = dt2.getZone();
    System.out.println(dt.withZone(dtz).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what a Date is: a universal instant in time. Choose the appropriate time zone when displaying it, and you'll have the time string you want:

```
Date now = new Date();
DateFormat df = df.getDateTimeInstance();
System.out.println(df.format(now)); // now, displayed in the current time zone (examle: Germany)
df.setTimeZone(theLondonTimeZone);
System.out.println(df.format(now)); // now, displayed in the time zone of London
```

Comment: I know i can implement that using date DateFormat, is there any way to write it down more generically so that i won't have to check all the time zones?

Comment: sorry I misinterpret your answer : in order to deal with unknown time zone I took the remote time and got the time zone from it, then used it with the current one.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "2012-10-30T22:30:00+0300" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" )
)
.toInstant()
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2012-10-30T19:30Z[Europe/London]

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatter to match your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" ) ;
```

Parse the input as a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
String input = "2012-11-05T13:00:00+0200" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2012-11-05T13:00+02:00

Tip: Always include the COLON character as a delimiter between the hours and minutes of the offset. We could then skip the custom formatting pattern: `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-11-05T13:00+02:00" )`.

Adjust to UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, by extracting a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

In standard ISO 8601 format, the `Z` on the end means UTC (offset of zero). Pronounced “Zulu”.

> instant.toString(): 2012-11-05T11:00:00Z

Adjust into London time.

```
ZoneId zLondon = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = instant.atZone( zLondon ) ;
```

> zdtLondon.toString(): 2012-11-05T11:00Z[Europe/London]

Adjust to another time zone.

```
ZoneId zMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = instant.atZone( zMontreal );
```

> zdtMontreal.toString(): 2012-11-05T06:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

All these objects (`odt`, `instant`, `zdtLondon`, and `zdtMontreal`)  represent the very same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKgbN.png
Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).